# Do remaining Dark Elixir gain goes to the storage or clan castle?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was wondering if I have a lvl 3 clan castle and get more than 1,000 dark elixir will it go directly to my storage and not in the clan castle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this right here is one of the bad things about clan wars. Sometimes you earn too much like you have right here. Sadly, if you earn more than your max amount that can be held in your clan castle in a clan war, or if you haven't collected it previously and it adds up, you don't get the extras. It does not go to storage or anything. It just disappears. Stupid, I know, but oh well, can't do anything about it. [Source](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/247051-17-4-2014-Maintenance-break-%28war-improvements%29)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not have enough space in your clan castle, you will loose that resources.